# Django sum boolean fields horizontally

Tags: django-models

I have a django model that records multiple user preferences horizontally.

```
class Preferences(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete='CASCADE')
    choice1 = models.BooleanField()
    choice2 = models.BooleanField()
    choice3 = models.BooleanField()
    choice4 = models.BooleanField()
    choice5 = models.BooleanField()
```

I'm trying to achieve the SQL query of:

```
(select 
(case when choice1 = True then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when choice2 = True then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when choice3 = True then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when choice4 = True then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when choice5 = True then 1 else 0 end) + as choice_sum
from Preferences)
```

How should I go about doing this in Django?

In case you want to know, I'm storing them horizontally as each user will have to record preferences for all choices which would increase in the future and I don't want multiple rows of unnecessary user FK.

Edit:

I realised my question might seem a bit weird. My objective is to eventually run a query that selects records where there is at least one True for any of the choices fields.

Answer (score 0):

> My objective is to eventually run a query that selects records where
>   there is at least one True for any of the choices fields.

Using Django filter + [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```
from django.db.models import Q
.....
.....

choices = Preferences.objects.filter(Q(choice1=True) | Q(choice2=True) | Q(choice3=True) | Q(choice4=True) | Q(choice5=True))
```